# Windows 10 Network Problems after deinstall Hyper-V

Tags: linux, windows-10, dns

My setup is the following: Windows 10 with 2 NICs 1 Nic for my network and internet access 2 Nic for my neighbour to access my files(different subnet)

Yesterday I deinstalled Hyper-V to do some testing with VirtualBox.

The Hyper-V Nics dissappeared from the Network Sharing Center and I deleted them from device manager. The origin NICs I configured again with the static IPs.

Now my problem is, I can't resolve the name of my neighbours Linux server and he can't resolve mine. Ping and accessing the shares from Windows to the Linux Server works, and only Ping from Linux to Windows works.

Internetaccess works fine over both NICs.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove the Vswitch before uninstalling?  You almost certainly should have done that.  I have never tried what you have described, but my guess is that the various network protocols were not properly rebound to your physical interfaces.

I would be strongly tempted to reinstall Hyper-V, then recreate the switch and remove it if you really need to.  I suspect this would restore things to the correct settings.

Also, you didn't really need to uninstall Hyper-V to use Virtual Box or another hypervisor.  You can configure an [alternate boot options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx) in Windows to boot with the Hyper-V disabled.

Comment: reinstalling hyper-v didn't do the trick. maybe a clean reinstall of windows might help.